# Ionic 2 - Div that slides up/down, pushing and pulling ion-content in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'am using Ionic 2 with Angular JS 2. What I want to do is add and remove a custom div on top of the ion-content which will smoothly slide down, pushing the ion-content when it appears and slides up, smoothly pulling ion-content back into place when it disappears.

Hope this image clears it up more,

[image]

I'm using animate.css for the custom bar to slide down. It doesn't look right as the ion-content gets pushed down before the animation starts. Is there a recommended way to achieve this type of functionality?

I want a pure angular 2 solution.

Comment: A plunker would good for this type of question